# Sending extra pram to jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I have a two field market select option and company input box.

Currently I am taking a market value and putting it into the session and calling the search company for autocomplete.

```
    // set market in session for searchCompnay
    sessionStorage.strategy_market = $("#market").val();
    $("#market").change(function() {
        sessionStorage.market = $("#market").val();
    });
    $("#symbol").autocomplete({source: searchCompany, minLength: 2 });
```

Search Company:

```
//function for searching companies
function searchCompany(request, response){
    var searchString = request.term;
    var callback =  function(status, jsondata){
        var availableTags = [];
        for(var i=0;i<jsondata.length;i++){
            var company = jsondata[i];
            availableTags.push(company.name);
        }
        response(availableTags);
    };
    callback.loadingDivId = "loadingDiv";
    SY.searchCompany(callback,sessionStorage.market,searchString,true);
}
```

I don't think setting session for sending market name for searching company is a good idea. Can any one suggest me a better way to do this.

P.s. I am using autocomplete searchCompany in many parts of my application.

Comment: What does `SY.searchCompany` do?

Comment: @putvande It calls a api and returns me a list of company in jsondata which I can access using jsondata[i].name

Comment: Shouldn't you add the extra parameter in that function?

Comment: @putvande I don't understand, which function? searchCompany or SY.searchCompany

Comment: @putvande Sorry their was typo.. that might have confuse you.. I had put sessionStorage.market extra parameter in that function, but I don't want to get it from session. I want some better way which I am not being able to think of